# Why GCC refuses a const reference within a copy-assignment operation?

Tags: c++, gcc, const-reference, copy-assignment, move-assignment-operator

I want to overload a common copy-assignment operator normally.
At first I used a interface that only requires a const reference to the source,
and explicitly disabled the interface that accepts a modifiable reference,
but I can not pass the compilation. 
The compiler reports "error: use of deleted function ‘ClassA& ClassA::operator=(ClassA&)"

Of course, I can get compiled if I don't expicitly delete the interface, but that is not my purpose.
I'd like to explicitly delete it, to avoid unexpected using it.

Why a copy-assignment operation needs a modifiable reference to the source, instead of a const reference?
The assignment operation just needs to access the source read-only!

There is a same question about the copy-constructor, I omit it for simplifying.

What's wrong with my code? or we can NOT delete it?

My sample code is following:

```
class ClassA {
public:
   ClassA() = default;
   ClassA( ClassA & ) = default;

   ClassA & operator=( ClassA & )
   = delete   // Must comment-out this, or we can't pass the compilation.
   // { cout << "ClassA & operator=( ClassA & ) executed." << endl; return *this; }
   ;

   ClassA & operator=( ClassA && ) {
      cout << "ClassA & operator=( ClassA && ) executed." << endl;
      return *this;
   };

   ClassA & operator=( const ClassA & ) {
      cout << "ClassA & operator=( const ClassA & ) executed." << endl;
      return *this;
   };
   ClassA & operator=( const ClassA && ) {
      cout << "ClassA & operator=( const ClassA && ) executed." << endl;
      return *this;
   };
};

int main() {
   ClassA oa, ob;
   ob = oa;

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
};
```

Comment: why would you need it? why changing yourself would change the other instance?

Comment: Accepting a `const` rvalue reference makes little sense due to nature of rvalue references.

Comment: You need to make up your mind.   Either use `ClassA &operator=(const ClassA &) = delete`  which prevents the compiler from generating the `operator=()` and means the class then doesn't have one,  or you define and implement the operator.    The two concepts are mutually exclusive.   You can't expect to explicitly delete an operator, and then explicitly implement it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> or we can NOT delete it?

You just don't need to do that. If you provide a user-defined copy assignment operator, then no other ones will be [implicitly-declared](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment#Implicitly-declared_copy_assignment_operator), i.e. only the user-defined one will exist.

If you do that, the copy assignment operator you explicitly marked as `delete` will participate in overload resolution; when it's selected the compilation fails. For `ob = oa;`, the `operator=( ClassA & )` is a better match, if it doesn't exist, `operator=( const ClassA & )` will be used and work fine.

So in this case you can just do

```
class ClassA {
public:

   ClassA & operator=( ClassA && ) {
      cout << "ClassA & operator=( ClassA && ) executed." << endl;
      return *this;
   }

   ClassA & operator=( const ClassA & ) {
      cout << "ClassA & operator=( const ClassA & ) executed." << endl;
      return *this;
   }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

> Of course, I can get compiled if I don't expicitly delete the interface, but that is not my purpose. I'd like to expicitly delete it, to avoid unexpected using it.

You cannot unexpectedly use something which does not exist. If your class defines `ClassA & operator=( const ClassA & )`, then `ClassA & operator=( ClassA & )` will not exist at all (the compiler will not generate that). There's no reason to provide & delete it.

Answer (score 1):

If you explicity delete it, and you call:

```
ob = oa;
// The same as
ob.operator=(oa);
```

Of course `ClassA & operator=( ClassA & )` is the best match as `oa` is a non-const lvalue. Since it is deleted, it will be an error.

If it is not declared at all, `ClassA & operator=( const ClassA & )` now becomes the best match. So it will never try to use `ClassA & operator=( ClassA & )` since it does not exist.

If you really wanted to, you could still have `ClassA & operator=( ClassA & ) = delete;`, and you would manually have to assign from const references:

```
ob = static_cast<const ClassA&>(oa);
// Will now select `ClassA & operator=( const ClassA & )`
```

This shows that you don't need a non-const lvalue assignment operator. But there is really no point, as it will be used as a const reference anyways if `ClassA & operator=( ClassA & )` is not declared.